# Image from non-recognised SD card partition on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, images, sd-card

I would like to back up an entire SD card into a single file on Windows 7. This SD card contains an two *ext3* partition which don't appear as a letter drive on Windows.

I've tried [Win32 Disk Imager](https://launchpad.net/win32-image-writer/+download), which seems to have a read option, but needs a letter (`F:`, `G:`, ...) to select the SD card drive.

Essentially, I'm after the Windows equivalent of this Linux command:

```
dd if=/dev/path/to/disk/device of=sdcard.img bs=1M
```

Is there any way to do this directly under Windows?

It would also be better if the resulting image was in a format that could be restore via `dd`, if copied onto a Linux machine.

(Although I'd prefer a single file for the who drive, a file per partition would also be fine.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If *win32 disk imager* just needs a drive letter so it knows which raw device to access, then you can give a drive letter to the SDcard partitions by installing a [driver for ext2 FS under windows](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2fsd/).

Personally I would just put it in a unix host (either real, in a VM or via a liveCD) because it is the way of least resistance and it is most likely to work.